# Unity Particle Collision 3D Game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add particles to my Collison but I receive errors. I keep getting his error from my code and I don't know why. The errors are: OnGUIDepth changed: was 0 is 1. Event type was 0 (56,60): error CS1001: Identifier expected. (56,55): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float horizontalInput;
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public float xRange = 100;
    private Animator playerAnim;
    public AudioClip crashSound;
    private AudioSource playerAudio;

    public GameObject projectilePrefab;
    public ParticleSystem explosionParticle;
    public bool isOnGround = true;
    public bool gameOver;
    


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.x < -xRange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        if (transform.position.x > xRange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
        }


        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, projectilePrefab.transform.rotation);
            Instantiate(projectilePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }


    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CampareTag("Rock"))
        {
            isOnGround = true;
        } else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Star"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Game Over");
            gameOver = true;
            playerAnim.SetBool("Death_b", true);
            playerAnim.SetInterger("DeathType_int", 1);
            explosionParticle.Play();
            playerAudio.PlayOneShot(crashSound, 1.0f);

        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to fix in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The errors here are already stated by the compiler and are an easy fix, just hover your mouse over and see what [intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) tells you

Let's go over this function

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CampareTag("Rock"))
    {
        isOnGround = true;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Star"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Game Over");
        gameOver = true;
        playerAnim.SetBool("Death_b", true);
        playerAnim.SetInterger("DeathType_int", 1);
        explosionParticle.Play();
        playerAudio.PlayOneShot(crashSound, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

In the first line, the

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision other)
```

'other' makes no sense to be there. The *Collision* is the type, and *collision* is the identifier. People often put other as the identifier which you might have gotten confused. Seeing you are using *other* as the variable in the function, you can remove collision from the brackets.

The function further contains just spelling errors, such as **.CampareTag** which needs to be CompareTag

Please strictly follow syntax and use intellisense, it is an incredible tool which will 100% eliminate such errors.

The other error (if an error at all, seems like just a log)

> OnGUIDepth changed: was 0 is 1. Event type was 0 (56,60):

is not contained within this script.